# How to get hex addresses in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm looking for a module / script to generate 64bit hex addresses in order

something like
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Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros

Comment: @JimBaldwin it's not a matter of padding. It's a matter of generating incremental 64bit HEX addresses

Comment: the examples you are typing in is not 64 bit. it is a 64digit hex string. 16^64, i am not sure if long long would even handle that, you need to be looking at some similar to BigInteger class in java or similar

Comment: @Ji_in_coding yeah maybe I'm a bit confused. Not my area of expertise. I want to get 64digit hex strings in order like the sequence above and increment so far that eventually i would get something like this
364957f65727f26434fd9ed59d110c16d26c799ec28f817a250d1a9c6bf8e588

Comment: @John, actually on Chrome, the max supported number is far greater than 16^64. you can get that max value by typing this in your browser console. Number.MAX_VALUE.toString(16). So,  the padding + increment method would theoretically work in your use case.

Comment: @John, I have just perform a test. in browser console type in this code. var x = parseInt('364957f65727f26434fd9ed59d110c16d26c799ec28f817a250d1a9c6bf8‌​e588', 16); x.toString(16);  You will see a loss of precision. So, your number is way too large. You should search for some big number javascript library.

Comment: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString(16) is 1fffffffffffff

Comment: @Ji_in_coding thanks for your support. I don't think I have the necessary knowledge for this. It seems I don't even know what I'm searching for.. I just know I need 64 digit hex strings. But I don't want the randomly, I want them ordered

Comment: @John, then the next question you should ask is, what is the likelihood of your numbers getting that large? if the likelihood is low, or it might take a long time before the number get that large. you can use Jim's answer to get past the current phase and work on the rest of your application. Just make a note that if the number gets too big, loss of precision will happen. Like I mentioned before, you need some kind of big number library. there are plenty out there. Ask google

Comment: @john Have a look at the solution I have provided and mark it as answer if that's what you wanted.

Comment: @RICKYKUMAR the problem is Number can't represent 64 hex digits.  That's why we had to break it down into 8 sections.

Answer (score 2):

You use this to generate in the way you want.

```js
var from = 0;
var to = 0x1f;
for(var i = from; i<= to;i++) {
  console.log(i.toString(16).padStart(64, "0"));
}
```

Comment: @John let me know if you need any help in understanding this code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE2:  code to generate a random 64-digit hex number string:

```
let x = '';
for (i=0; i<64; i++) {
    x += Math.trunc((Math.random() * 16)).toString(16);
}
```

UPDATE:  this is absurd, but it should work:

```
let pad = '00000000';
for (let d7=0; d7<0x100; d7++) {
  for (let d6=0; d6<0x100; d6++) {
    for (let d5=0; d6<0x100; d5++) {
      for (let d4=0; d6<0x100; d4++) {
        for (let d3=0; d6<0x100; d3++) {
          for (let d2=0; d6<0x100; d2++) {
            for (let d1=0; d6<0x100; d1++) {
              for (let d0=0; d6<0x100; d0++) {
                console.log(
                  (pad + d7.toString(16)).slice(-8) 
                  + (pad + d6.toString(16)).slice(-8)
                  + (pad + d5.toString(16)).slice(-8)
                  + (pad + d4.toString(16)).slice(-8)
                  + (pad + d3.toString(16)).slice(-8)
                  + (pad + d2.toString(16)).slice(-8)
                  + (pad + d1.toString(16)).slice(-8)
                  + (pad + d0.toString(16)).slice(-8))
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how do I make it go continuously? from 0 to w/e is on the end?

Comment: The limit is set to 0x20 in my example (matching your post).  You can make that a variable, or also do this with an infinite while loop, or a bunch of different ways.

Comment: but would i be able to get something like this? 
364957f65727f26434fd9ed59d110c16d26c799ec28f817a250d1a9c6bf8e588

Comment: Updated to support 64-bit numbers.  But you are showing 256-bit numbers.  Do you really mean 256-bit?

Comment: I really have no idea. maybe this is way above my understanding. I just know I need 64 digit hex strings. But I don't want the randomly, I want them ordered

Comment: The code above is running, but it will take years to verify. :-P

Comment: yeah I think that worked.. pasted that by mistake in the console and chrome almost caught fire. I'll try to put it in node and maybe do chunks at a time. thanks for help

Comment: ok so I tried this over 1000 iterations and I end up with too many 0. no way this code would generate a string like 364957f65727f26434fd9ed59d110c16d26c799ec28f817a250d1a9c6bf8e583

Comment: Are you just looking for random numbers?

Comment: as I said before, no. I'm looking for an ordered sequence

Comment: You're never going to get to a large number like that in order on any computer that will exist for the next 20 years.  If you can be a little more clear on what you want, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Without using a big number library, you could create a class that extends `Array` with a constructor that takes the hex string representation of a number and provide increment (`inc`) and string conversion (`toString`) class methods. E.G.

```js
const MAX_BITS = 256;                      // bits for 64 hex digits
const USHORTS = Math.ceil(MAX_BITS / 16);  // handled 16 bits at a time 

class U256 extends Array {
    constructor( hexString) {
        super();
        for( var i = hexString.length; i > 0; i-=4) {
             var ushortHex = hexString.substring (i, i-4);
             this.push( parseInt(ushortHex, 16));      
        }
        while( this.length < USHORTS) {
             this.push(0);
        }
    }
    inc() {
          for( var i = 0; i < USHORTS; ++i) {
              var ushort = this[i];
              ++ushort;
              if(ushort < 0x10000) {
                 this[i] = ushort;
                 break;
              }
              this[i]=0;
          }
          return this;
    }
    toString() {
        var hex64 = "";
        for( var i = USHORTS; i--;) {
            var hex4 = this[i].toString(16);
            hex64 += hex4.padStart(4, '0');
        }
        return hex64;              
    }
}

var u256 = new U256( "FFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
for( var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    console.log( u256.toString())
    u256.inc();
}
```